# Rails 4.2.7 & Devise 4.1.1 - Change password with current password required in user preferences page with AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

My application has three different user types (i.e. Devise models): `SuperAdminUser`, `AdminUser` and `StandardUser`. Every user, regardless of type, has a preferences page where they will be able to update a number of attributes (e.g. `:email`, `:password`, `:username`, etc.), with two of the attributes requiring the user to enter their current password to update (`:email`, `:password`), while the remaining attributes will not require the current password to update.

Now, in my ideal world, the preference updates will utilize AJAX so that only the attribute changed will refresh in the page rather than an entire page reload. Currently I have this working for all of the attributes that don't require the user to enter their current password, but I've been unable to get it to work with `:email` and `:password`.  Oddly enough, I have it working in a previous prototype, but that had only one Devise user model, not three, and that single model didn't have it's own registration controller overriding the Devise registration controller, which the three user models in the current app do, although I don't see anything in these overriding registration controllers that would be impacting the issue here.

The only error message I'm getting is my own, on the preferences page:

```
Sorry, but we were unable to update your password.
```

The problem appears to be that the `:current_password` param value is not being captured from the form. The console log statement shows it as a blank string, while the `:new_password` and `:new_password_confirmation` values are captured without problem. I haven't been able to determine why this is happening. As an alternate approach, I also tried to mimic as closely as I could the change password example in the Devise wiki (the last example) (here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password), but to no avail. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Additionally, I guess an important question to ask is if should I be using AJAX with the password attribute.  That is, is it inherently insecure passing these password values via AJAX? If so, is there a way to do it securely (e.g. encrypted)?

Here is my relevant code:

**app/controllers/super_admin_users/preferences_controller.rb**

```
class SuperAdminUsers::PreferencesController < ApplicationController

  include ApplicationHelper
  before_action :authenticate_super_admin_user!
  .
  .
  .
  def change_password
    @super_admin_user = SuperAdminUser.find_by(id: current_super_admin_user.id)
    if resource.update_with_password(params.permit(:password,
                                                   :password_confirmation,
                                                   :current_password))
      sign_in resource_name, self.resource, bypass: true
      status_message = 'Your password has been updated successfully!'
    else
      status_message = 'Sorry, but we were unable to update your password.'
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: { status_message: status_message } }
    end
  end

  def password_section_partial
    @change_password_status_message = params[:change_password_status_message] || ""
    render 'super_admin_users/preferences/password/password_section_partial'
  end
  .
  .
  .
    end
end
```

**app/views/super_admin_users/preferences/password/_change_password_form.html.haml**

```
= form_tag super_admin_user_prefs_change_password_path, id: 'prefs-change-password-form' do
  .prefs-label-and-input-wrapper
    #prefs-new-password-label-wrapper.prefs-input-label-wrapper
      = label_tag 'password', 'New Password', id:           'prefs-new-password-label',
                                              class:        'prefs-input-label'
    #prefs-new-password-input-wrapper.prefs-input-wrapper
      = password_field_tag 'password', nil,   autofocus:     true,
                                              autocomplete: 'off',
                                              id:           'prefs-new-password-input',
                                              class:        'prefs-input'
  .prefs-label-and-input-wrapper
    #prefs-new-password-confirmation-label-wrapper.prefs-input-label-wrapper
      = label_tag 'password_confirmation', 'New Password Confirmation', id:           'prefs-new-confirmation-password-label',
                                                                        class:        'prefs-input-label'
    #prefs-new-password-confirmation-input-wrapper.prefs-input-wrapper
      = password_field_tag 'password_confirmation', nil,                autocomplete: 'off',
                                                                        id:           'prefs-new-password-confirmation-input',
                                                                        class:        'prefs-input'
  .prefs-label-and-input-wrapper
    #prefs-current-password-label-wrapper.prefs-input-label-wrapper
      = label_tag 'current_password', 'Current Password', id:           'prefs-current-password-label',
                                                          class:        'prefs-input-label'
    #prefs-current-password-input-wrapper.prefs-input-wrapper
      = password_field_tag 'current_password', nil,       autocomplete: 'off',
                                                          id:           'prefs-current-password-input',
                                                          class:        'prefs-input'
  #prefs-change-password-form-buttons-wrapper
    #prefs-change-password-form-submit-btn-wrapper
      = link_to 'Update', 'javascript:;', id: 'prefs-change-password-form-submit-btn', class: 'btn btn-sm btn-success btn-submit'
      -#%input{ id: 'prefs-change-password-form-submit-btn', class: 'btn btn-sm btn-success', type: 'submit', value: 'Update' }
    #prefs-change-password-form-cancel-btn-wrapper
      = link_to 'Cancel', 'javascript:;', id: 'prefs-change-password-form-cancel-btn', class: 'btn btn-sm btn-secondary btn-cancel'
```

**app/views/super_admin_users/preferences/password/_change_password_status_message.html.haml**

```
#prefs-change-password-status-message.prefs-status-message= change_password_status_message
```

**app/views/super_admin_users/preferences/password/_password_section.html.haml**

```
#prefs-password-section-header.prefs-section-header
  #prefs-password-headline-wrapper
    .prefs-section-headline Password
  #prefs-password-edit-btn-wrapper
    = link_to 'Edit', 'javascript:;', id: 'prefs-password-edit-btn', class: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-edit'
#prefs-change-password-form-wrapper.prefs-form-wrapper.no-display
  = render partial: 'super_admin_users/preferences/password/change_password_form'
#prefs-change-password-status-message-wrapper.prefs-status-message-wrapper.no-display
```

**app/views/super_admin_users/preferences/password/password_section_partial.js.haml**

```
$('#prefs-change-password-status-message-wrapper').empty();
$('#prefs-change-password-form-wrapper').addClass('no-display');
$('#prefs-change-password-form').trigger('reset');

- if @change_password_status_message.present?
  $('#prefs-change-password-status-message-wrapper').append("#{ escape_javascript(render(partial: 'super_admin_users/preferences/password/change_password_status_message', locals: { change_password_status_message: @change_password_status_message })) }");
  $('#prefs-change-password-status-message-wrapper').removeClass('no-display');

$('#prefs-password-edit-btn').removeClass('no-display');
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  include ApplicationHelper
  include DeviseParamSanitizerOverrides

  def get_current_user_type
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: { current_user_type: resource_name.to_s } }
    end
  end

  def get_current_environment
     respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: { current_environment: Rails.env } }
    end
  end

  protected

    def devise_parameter_sanitizer
      if resource_class.to_s == 'SuperAdminUser'
        SuperAdminUser::ParameterSanitizer.new(SuperAdminUser, :super_admin_user, params)
      elsif resource_class.to_s == 'AdminUser'
        AdminUser::ParameterSanitizer.new(AdminUser, :admin_user, params)
      elsif resource_class.to_s == 'StandardUser'
        StandardUser::ParameterSanitizer.new(StandardUser, :standard_user, params)
      end
    end

end
```

**app/controllers/concerns/devise_param_sanitizer_overrides.rb**

```
module DeviseParamSanitizerOverrides

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class SuperAdminUser::ParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer
    def initialize(*)
      super
      permit(:sign_up,        keys: [:email, :first_name, :last_name, :username])
      permit(:sign_in,        keys: [:email, :username])
      permit(:account_update, keys: [:current_password, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :time_zone, :username])
    end
  end
.
.
.
end
```

**app/helpers/application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper

    def resource
      if super_admin_user_signed_in?
        @super_admin_user ||= SuperAdminUser.new
      elsif admin_user_signed_in?
        @admin_user       ||= AdminUser.new
      elsif standard_user_signed_in?
        @standard_user    ||= StandardUser.new
      end
    end

    def resource_name
      if super_admin_user_signed_in?
        :super_admin_user
      elsif admin_user_signed_in?
        :admin_user
      elsif standard_user_signed_in?
        :standard_user
      end
    end

    def resource_class
      if super_admin_user_signed_in?
        SuperAdminUser
      elsif admin_user_signed_in?
        AdminUser
      elsif standard_user_signed_in?
        StandardUser
      end
    end

    def devise_mapping
      if super_admin_user_signed_in?
        @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:super_admin_user]
      elsif admin_user_signed_in?
        @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:admin_user]
      elsif standard_user_signed_in?
        @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:standard_user]
      end
    end

    def resource_authenticated_root
      if super_admin_user_signed_in?
        authenticated_super_admin_user_root
      elsif admin_user_signed_in?
        authenticated_admin_user_root
      elsif standard_user_signed_in?
        authenticated_standard_user_root
      end
    end

end
```

**app/assets/javascripts/preferences.js**

```
var currentUserType;
var currentEnvironment;

getCurrentUserType('/get_current_user_type'
).done(function(getCurrentUserTypeResponse) {
  currentUserType = getCurrentUserTypeResponse.current_user_type;
});

getCurrentEnvironment('/get_current_environment'
).done(function(getCurrentEnvironmentResponse) {
  currentEnvironment = getCurrentEnvironmentResponse.current_environment;
});


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#prefs-password-edit-btn').click(function (e) {
    $('#prefs-password-edit-btn').addClass('no-display');
    $('#prefs-change-password-form').trigger('reset');
    $('#prefs-change-password-form-wrapper').removeClass('no-display');
  });

  $(function() {
    return $('body').on('click', '#prefs-change-password-form-submit-btn', function() {
      $('#prefs-change-password-form-wrapper').addClass('no-display');
      changePassword('/' + currentUserType + 's/preferences/change_password?password='              + $('#prefs-new-password-input').val() +
                                                                          '&password_confirmation=' + $('#prefs-new-password-confirmation-input').val() +
                                                                          '&current_password='      + $('#prefs-current-password-input').val()
      ).done(function(changePasswordResponse) {
        $.ajax({url: '/' + currentUserType + 's/preferences/password_section_partial?change_password_status_message=' + changePasswordResponse.status_message});
      });
    });
  });

  $(function() {
    return $('body').on('click', '#prefs-change-password-form-cancel-btn', function() {
      $('#prefs-change-password-form-wrapper').addClass('no-display');
      $('#prefs-change-password-form').trigger('reset');
      $('#prefs-password-edit-btn').removeClass('no-display');
    });
  });


function getCurrentUserType(url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json'
  })
  .fail(function() {
    if (currentEnvironment === 'development') {
      alert('AJAX Get Current User Type Error');
    }
  })
}

function getCurrentEnvironment(url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json'
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert('AJAX Get Current Environment Error');
  })
}

function changePassword(url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json'
  })
  .fail(function() {
    if (currentEnvironment === 'development') {
      alert('AJAX Change Password Error');
    }
  })
}
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/get_current_user_type',   to: 'application#get_current_user_type'
  get '/get_current_environment', to: 'application#get_current_environment'
  .
  .
  .
  devise_for :super_admin_users, controllers: { registrations: 'super_admin_users/registrations' }

  authenticated :super_admin_user do
    root to: 'super_admin_users/dashboard#index', as: 'authenticated_super_admin_user_root'
  end

  as :super_admin_user do
    get  'super_admin_users/preferences/password_section_partial', to: 'super_admin_users/preferences#password_section_partial',
                                                                   as: :super_admin_user_password_section_partial
    get  'super_admin_users/preferences/change_password',          to: 'super_admin_users/preferences#change_password',
                                                                   as: :super_admin_user_prefs_change_password
  end

end
```